# Write a shell script and list all the user who logged in five minutes ago

Tags: shell, unix

Write a shell script and list all the user who logged in five minutes ago.
Suppose not time is 3:12AM , I want to list all the users who logged in at 3:07Am or after 3:07AM
I tried the following steps
there is `file w.sh` which contain the script this

```
Step 1:   `who >>/home/user/log.txt`
Step 2: now run the script `w.sh ` using `crontab`
Step 3: `* * * * * /home/user/w.sh`
```

this will run for every minutes every hour everyday every weeks every months

```
Step 4: i want to check for last 5 minutes 
`cat log.txt |grep "    "`  NOW I 'm STUCK
```

how to list out all the users 
Please help me. 
Is it possible to make a single script instead of doing all four steps ??

Answer (score 4):

The script below does what you want:

```
#! /bin/bash

input=$(who)

perl -alne '
    $date = "$F[2] $F[3]";
    $epoch = `date -d "$date" +%s`;
    $_5ago = `date -d "5 minutes ago" +%s`;
    $now = `date -d "now" +%s`;
    if ( $epoch >= $_5ago && $epoch <= $now ){
        print "$F[0]" ;
    }
' <<< "$input"
```

EXPLANATION:

The output of `who` has its date information on fields 3 and 4:

`tiago    tty1         2014-06-07 22:04`

Using perl the script converts these fields to epoch and checks if fits into the range between now and 5 minutes ago also in epoch, if so print field 1 which is the user.

Answer (score 0):

This `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%s")
who|while read user term dt; do
   logon=$(date -j -f "%b %d %H:%M" "$dt" "+%s")
   if (( now - logon < 300 ));then
      echo $user
   fi
done
```

Will work for this `who` type output:

```
$ who
klashxx  console  Jun 21 16:21 
klashxx  ttys000  Jun 21 16:21 
klashxx  ttys001  Jun 21 21:33
```

Comment: not getting any output , script is unable to read the values of dt h m